# Swift Spritekit change color of node when tapped multiple times

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, touchesbegan

i am trying to get it to change the fillcolor of a node on my menuscene based on colors in an array.

I have an array filled with 4 colors, and when I press the node it should filter through those colors based on the position. So when I tap the node once it should change color to red, if I tap it again it changes to green, another tap would change it to purple, and then back to blue

```
var colors = [UIColor.blue, UIColor.red, UIColor.green, UIColor.purple]

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first!
    var index = 0
    if changeColor.contains(touch.location(in: self)) {
        index += 1
        changeColor.fillColor = colors[index]
        if index == 3 {
            index = 0
        }
    }
}
```

However, this only reads one tap, and I need it register multiple taps

Comment: I think its reading the taps, but you are resetting index to 0 every time this function runs so you will only see the first color in the array. Move var index = 0 outside of the function should do it

Comment: also move the index += 1 after you change the color or you will never see the color ins colors[0]

Comment: index is getting reset each time you enter touchesBegan(). move it out-of scope so that way it will persist in-between calls.

Answer (score 2):

move initialization of the index outside the touches begin function and increment the index after changing the color.

```
var colors = [UIColor.blue, UIColor.red, UIColor.green, UIColor.purple]
var index = 0

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first!

    if changeColor.contains(touch.location(in: self)) {
        changeColor.fillColor = colors[index]
        index += 1

        if index == colors.count {
            index = 0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, change then name of `index` to `currentNodeColor` or similar.

Comment: @SteveIves I do agree that is a much better and descriptive name for the variable, though it isn't necessary for the code to work, but makes it much more readable